# Which programs have tried to access protected folders blocked by Windows ransomware defender?

Tags: windows-10, security

In short: **Is it possible to list programs that Windows has denied access to a protected folder?**

I recently enabled the Ransomware protection functionality in Windows Defender, adding a series of folders to the Controlled Folder Access list.  Some of these folders are under Git version control (via Github Desktop), or synchronised using Syncthing (via SyncTrayzor).  I've added the canonical versions of `git.exe` and `syncthing.exe` within `C:/Program Files` to the Allowed App list, but I now receive messages telling me that windows has blocked attempts to access files in protected folders by `C:/Users/.../git.exe` and  `C:/Users/.../syncthing.exe`.

Annoyingly, the ellipsis hides most of the path to the executable file.  A windows search of my user directory eventually turns up a number of copies of `git.exe`, and it's not immediately clear which of these was trying to edit the files.  Ransomware protection's limited user interface means it takes ages to add each file individually, and this seems like a poor security choice: a smart attacker might entitle their malware `git.exe` to trick me into allowing access.

How can I see the full path of the blocked file (particularly after the notification prompt has disappeared from my screen)?

I can't see anything relevant in the Windows event log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of recently blocked apps in Windows Defender settings.

To see the list of apps that are blocked, click on the **Add an allowed app** button, and click **Recently blocked apps**.

*via [How to Configure Controlled Folder Access to Stop "Unauthorized changes blocked" Notifications](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/use-controlled-folder-access-windows-10-windows-defender/)*

[image]

Alternately, open a Command Prompt window to run this command:

```
wevtutil qe "Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational" /q:"*[System[(EventID=1123)]]" /c:15 /f:text /rd:true | findstr /i "process name:"
```

This shows the list of the last 15 items blocked by Defender's Controlled Folder Access.

[image]

Comment: When I click "Add an allowed app", I just see an "open file" dialog box: I don't see the popup displayed in your screenshot.

Comment: The new option was introduced in `v1809` (i think). For older builds, you can see the file names in the Event Viewer, or use the PowerShell script in that article.